# Real time plotting of serial data between python and arduino

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

For the mapping of the obstacles in a region, I was planning on using Sharp IR range finders connected with an Arduino Mega and then trying to plot it in real time on a polar histogram type map using python and matplotlib. I was a bit confused about how to proceed through the interfacing of the Arduino and python over the serial connection.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good start: [Arduino and Python](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python).  Summary: use pySerial and read from/write to `/dev/tty.usbserial`.

See also:

[How to send a value from Arduino to Python and then use that value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118890/how-to-send-a-value-from-arduino-to-python-and-then-use-that-value?rq=1)

[Receive multiple values via pyserial and display in Python GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154341/receive-multiple-values-via-pyserial-and-display-in-python-gui?rq=1)